# gdb: Undefined output format "z"

Tags: c, linux, gcc, gdb, debian

I want to debug my code with gdb on BeagleBone Black Board. I want to print my variable as hex in gdb and in order to do that I have always used `p/z` as gdb command. But when I use this command in gdb in BeagleBlack I've got:

```
Undefined output format "z".
```

Is there any way that I make it working? Does it relate to gdb version? my operating system is Debian and my gdb version is: `7.4.1-debian` and when I try to install new package it says: `gdb is already the newest version`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The print format `z` was added relatively recently ( I think, it's 7.6 or 7.7 - based on [this patch](https://sourceware.org/ml/gdb-patches/2013-07/msg00319.html)). Since you are using a older version of gdb, it doesn't recognize the `z` option. You can use `p/x` instead.

The difference [between `x` and `z` is the leading zeros](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Output-Formats.html):

> z
>       Like ‘x’ formatting, the value is treated as an integer and printed as hexadecimal, but leading zeros are printed to pad the value
>   to the size of the integer type.

The GDB on my system is release 7.9 and it does recognize `p/z`. So either you can upgrade your GDB or use `p/x`.